# Jasper report excel cutting off cell

Tags: jasper-reports, apache-poi, ireport

I want to export to excel, but I want the data to print in a cell irregardless of how much data it is.  I have tried setting the "Stretch with Overflow" option and that appears to work, but it creates empty rows between actual data rows.  I tried adding the IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS to true and it does not resolve my issue.  I am also using IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION.

Ideally I want excel exports to just put all the data in a cell independent of the size of the cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.  You need to set the `net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text` report parameter to `true`

Answer (score 0):

@DMoses: I had the problem of the empty rows a lot using the "Stretch with Overflow" and it was generated because I left unconsciously a space between the cell where I display the data and the margin of the report. Just put the cell at the edge of the margin and then you won't have that problem.

Comment: I thought that was the issue at first also, but I made sure that all the textfields where the height/width of the band.  In fact I reduced the report to just column header and detail band with two fields/columns and I still had the issue (I made sure they were pixel perfect).

Comment: Hmm... I think we set all the parameters as true in the JasperReports so I never saw that problem, only with the textfields. I will do an experiment with what you just said.

Comment: I should note that it worked fine exporting to older xls, just not the newer xlsx if I recall correctly.  In any case the full.text property is what I really wanted, since my business likes the rows all the same height.